# How to send int array with ESP8266 http post request?

Tags: esp8266, array, rfid, http

I'm reading RFID cards' `UID` with an ESP8266 and trying to send that information to my web server hosted on a Raspberry Pi. I'm currently storing the `UID` in an int array, but the `http.POST();` function takes a string input. I tried adding each `UID` digit together, but that doesn't work either.

How would you go about sending the uid in the request?

My code:

```cpp
    /*
    Created by TheCircuit
*/

#define SS_PIN 4  //D2
#define RST_PIN 5 //D1

#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char* ssid = "****";
const char* password = "****";
const char* serverName = "****";
int RELAY = 2; //D6

int UIDs[1][4] = {
  {83, 111, 39, 47}
};

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522

  pinMode(RELAY, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

boolean compareUIDs(int a[4], int b[4]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (a[i] != b[i]) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

void loop()
{
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
  {
    return;
  }

  // mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

  int UID[4];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    UID[i] = mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i];
  }

  Serial.print(UID[0]);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(UID[1]);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(UID[2]);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(UID[3]);
  Serial.println();

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(UIDs); i++) {
    boolean success = compareUIDs(UIDs[i], UID);
    if (success) {
      Serial.println("ACCESS GRANTED");
      digitalWrite(RELAY, LOW);

      if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
        HTTPClient http;

        // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
        http.begin(serverName);

        // Specify content-type header
        http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
        int httpResponseCode = http.POST("UID GOES HERE");

        Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
        Serial.println(httpResponseCode);

        // Free resources
        http.end();
      }

      delay(2000);
      digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You encode it in some string format that the website at the remote end is expecting. Either as a HTTP parameter list, or as a JSON array string, or whatever is needed.

Comment: @Majenko could you give me a link or short explanation to get started on that one?

Comment: It looks like you've already decided on (or had imposed on you) JSON.  So the simplest method is to use ArduinoJSON (https://arduinojson.org/) to create the JSON string for you.

Comment: my StreamLib has CStringBuilder to `print` to string same way as you print to Serial

Comment: you could send it as an integer ... that UID in your code is 536f272f

Answer (score 1):

You could use the (awesome) ArduinoJSON library, but likely overkill for this app. I found it more useful to parse JSON than to construct it.

You could simply print to a buffer and the POST that:

```
char payload[MAX_PAYLOAD];
sprintf(payload, "{\"uid1\":%d,\"uid2\":%d,\"uid3\":%d,\"uid4\":%d}", UID[0], UID[1], UID[2], UID[3]);

http.POST(payload);
```

You would `#define MAX_PAYLOAD` with a value that will be sufficient to hold all the information.

Notice that `sprintf` allows you to use any formatting options you want (e.g. hexadecimal, etc).

If you wanted to send it as an array:

```cpp
sprintf(payload, "{\"uid\":[%d,%d,%d,%d]}", UID[0], UID[1], UID[2], UID[3]);
```